# JavaScript/HTML/CSS - Multiple forms on one page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple web page in JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. The web page generates 5 div elements. Each div element includes a random number, text input, and submit button. My code below does that.

The user then should be able to enter the random number into the text input box and click the submit button. The script should check if they entered the correct answer or not.

I'm not sure if this is possible? I understand how to write the code for just a single form on the page but this example is using 5 forms on a single page that are dynamically generated. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <style type="text/css">
       #test {
           width:250px;
            padding:10px;
            border:5px solid gray;
            margin:10px;

        }
     </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <script>

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        document.write('<div id="test">');
        var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        document.write(ranNum);
        document.write("<p>Enter the number above:</p>");
        document.write("<form id=\"form1\" name=\"form1\" method=\"post\" action=\"\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"answer\" id=\"answer\" /><input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" id=\"button\" value=\"Submit\" /></form>");
        document.write('</div>');
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In order to submit each form without having the page reload, use AJAX.

Comment: Are you saying you want to test the entered value client-side in JavaScript, without submitting to the web server? Note that you should not have more than one element with the same `id`, so if you're creating elements in a loop perhaps append the loop counter to the end of each `id` so that they'll be unique. Given you are using `#test` to style the divs I suggest changing that to use a class name `<div class="test">` and `.test { ... }`.

Comment: FWIW, you can only have one ID named `test` on the page. Maybe use a class name instead on type wrapper div, or spend the iteration index to the ID. (Same goes with the form's ID)-- *edit* nnnnnn beat New to it. Guess I took too long to respond on my phone. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't even interact with the server to check if it was the correct answer.
So, yes, you can easily do that.
Use jquery, make those numbers properties to a global object, properties named after `#id` of your inputs, so when user clicks, just compare the value of input with the property of your global object with the same name.

eg:

```
window.myObject = {}

myObject.div1 = // your code for random number
myObject.div2 = // again, code for random number
```

And so on, even better put your random number code into a function and call 
it for each property.

then just set the divs values as properties:

```
$("div.div1").append("<span class='value'>" + myObject.div1 + "</span>");
```

Or maybe even you could create a loop to do it so you don't need to type it for all divs.

After that, test your inputs:

```
$("div.div1").find("submit").click(function(){
    // here you collect the data from your form, lazy to type
    // and test it for equality with coresponding myObject.div1 
    // or with the value in <span class="value>
    //e.g.
    if ($(this).parent().find(".mytextinput").val() == $(this).parent().find("span.value").val())
        { //do something} else {//do something else }
});
```

Of course, this presumes you can use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

as has been pointed out in the comments, make sure id's are always unique. I wouldn't use ajax for something this simple, you can check the values client side. See below for a working solution.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.write('<div id="div-' + i + '">');
    var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    document.write(ranNum);
    document.write("<p>Enter the number above:</p>");
    document.write("<form id=\"form-" + i + "\" name=\"form-" + i + "\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"answer\" id=\"answer-" + i + "\" /><input type=\"submit\" name=\"button\" id=\"button-" + i + "\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=\"checkAnswer(this); return false;\"/></form>");
    document.write('</div>');
}
function checkAnswer(element) {
    var thisAnswer=element.form.parentElement.textContent.substring(0,1);
    var answerGiven=element.form.children[0].value;
    if (thisAnswer==answerGiven) {
        alert("correct!");
    } else {
        alert("wrong!");
    }
}
```